# Entity Framework 6 (code-first) - composite foreign key

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-6, ef-code-first, foreign-keys

I'm working with Entity Framework (code-first) for the first time and I can't figure out how to accomplish a specific foreign key.

My code looks something like this:

```
public class Customer
{
    [Key]
    [Index("IX_Customer_Entity", IsUnique = true, Order = 1)]
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }

    [Index("IX_Customer_Entity", IsUnique = true, Order = 2)]
    public EntityType EntityType { get; set; } //1

    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
}

public class Supplier
{
    [Key]
    [Index("IX_Supplier_Entity", IsUnique = true, Order = 1)]
    public int SupplierID { get; set; }

    [Index("IX_Supplier_Entity", IsUnique = true, Order = 2)]
    public EntityType EntityType { get; set; } //2

    public string SupplierName { get; set; }
}

public class Note
{
    [Key]
    public int NoteID { get; set; }

    [Index("IX_Parent", 1)]
    public int ParentID { get; set; }

    [Index("IX_Parent", 2)]
    public EntityType ParentType { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Now I want to create a relation between `Customer` and `Note`, and between `Supplier` and `Note`, but not using the primary key of the `Note` table.

The result in SQL looks like this:

[SQL diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JBnFM.png)

Can someone please tell me how to do this?